# Get pixel to mm ratio from image

Tags: image-processing

Is is possible to get pixel to mm ration from image exif. I have focal length of camera, image resolution, as well as camera distance from object in image (outside exif).

I have distance from origin (X, Y) in meters, and I need to figure out how to use those coordinates in pixels in order to move image.

Comment: You would also need sensor size, leaving it as trigonometry problem.

Comment: And also account for spherical aberrations/distortion in the lens.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height or width of an object and it’s distance, you can trace out a triangle. The vertex is the center of lens.  Example an object is 2 meter in height, 8 meters from the camera -- the length of the base of this triangle is 2 meters, the height of this triangle is 8 meters. Bisect the triangle and ½ the base is 1 meter. The ratio of base to height is 1 ÷ 8 =  0.125.

Inside the camera, the projected image of this object traces out a similar triangle. The vertex is at the center of the rear lens element. The height of this triangle is the focal length. Suppose the lens has a focal length of 75mm. The height of the  image as projected on the sensor will be 2 X 75 X 0.125 = 9.375 X 2 = 18.75mm.

Technically the measurement points associated with the lens is the front and rear nodal points. You will not easily discover their locations. If the subject is a meter or so distant, you need not worry, such a small inaccuracy is moot. Likely if you use the rear element as the rear nodal your calculation will also be satisfactory. If not, refine the height of the in-camera triangle by trial and error to improve accuracy.

Comment: MIght be helpful to add a drawing of a lens w/ the chief and marginal (a and b) rays.

Answer (score 0):

There are EXIF tags for recording the resolution, but those are intended for scanners that have a known scanning resolution. A camera can have wildly different distances to the subject, so the resolution is essentially unknowable. The [EXIF spec](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) states "When the image resolution is unknown, 72 [dpi] is designated."

Calculating the resolution of an actual scene involves lots of variables: sensor size and resolution, distance to subject, lens focal length, lens distortions, focus breathing - and those are just the ones I can think of off the top of my head. If you really need to know, your best bet is to take a picture of something whose size is known and count how many pixels it takes in the final image. Then simply divide pixels/size.